# How can I configure time zones on my Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, time-zones

Yesterday I got a meeting email which I read on my SGS GT-I9000, which showed the time as:

> Wednesday, January 12, 2011 8:30 AM-9:00 AM (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

But when I checked this on my PC in Outlook this was the time:

> Wednesday, January 12, 2011 7:00 PM-7:30 PM (GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi

How can I get my device to use the same time zone as my PC?

Comment: 9am - (-5) = 2pm UTC, 7:30pm - (5:30) = 2pm UTC.  So both messages show the same time, just for different time zones.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that your PC and your Android are in different time zones. Since you've already mentioned that you're in India, I expect that your Android has the wrong setting.

`Settings | Date & time`

You may have to turn off "Automatic" so that you can set the time zone yourself.

Comment: thanks, i have turn off automatic setting in [setting->date time], there is no option for entering time zone on my self and there is no item in list where i find India so how to change it.

Comment: Can't help you. I have a Droid and can only share the settings that I find on it. I don't know what sort of customizations Samsung may have done.

Comment: @Jeevan My Galaxy S has "Select time zone" in Settings -> Date & time.  Automatic should work if you have a SIM card in the phone, however.

Comment: @Mathew: it is in automatic mode and i have sim on it.

Comment: @Jeevan on my Galaxy S, if I take the tick out of Automatic I am able to select a time zone, and one of the options is GMT+5:30 Kolkata which sounds like the zone you need?